# slug laravel override login

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, slug

I have a route in web.php like this

`Route::get('/{slug_category}', 'WelcomeController@cdetail')->name('cdetail');`

its success when I access category like /action, /horror, etc

but this route was overridden my default /login laravel

how can I fix the /login route?

I already add if else in the controller, but I don't know what I must return to the login page

[image]

Comment: `if($slug_category= 'login') != if($slug_category == 'login')`

Comment: If you define your `login` route first, it should not be of a problem. Are you calling `Auth::routes()` or defining your routes after this specific route ? Can you share your `web.php` ?

Comment: thanks matia i forgot that, I put Auth::Routes below the slug route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your login route before your slug_category route

```php
Route::get('/login', ...);

Route::get('/{slug_category}', 'WelcomeController@cdetail')->name('cdetail');
```

Or if you use default laravel auth you can use like this.

```php
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{slug_category}', 'WelcomeController@cdetail')->name('cdetail');
```